# Python How to run a function n times concurrently at Same time

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I want to run the function example() n number of times at same time without any delay concurrently, this current script is able to run n number of times but there is almost milliseconds of difference between each call. I want the function to be hit at same time. Is there any better way to do it ?
I used multiprocess too in past, but it was slowing down my computer if I run more than n=100.
Please suggest a good way

```
import threading,argparse,sys,subprocess
from time import strftime
    def example(a):
        time= strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        print("Hello" +a)
        print(time) # It should be same for all n concurrent, since we want all to hit same time

def main(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Hello")
    parser.add_argument("-n", type=str, dest="n")
    parser.add_argument("-a", type=str, dest="a")
    global verbose
    global simulated
    verbose = args.verbose
    n = args.n
    a = args.a

    for counter in range(1, int(n) + 1):
        try:
            t = threading.Thread(name="thread" + str(counter), target=example, args=(a))
            t.start()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        ret = main(sys.argv[1:])
        sys.exit(ret)
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Error' + str(ex))
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: _"I used multiprocess"_. Hmm? This code isn't using `multiprocessing`, it's using `threading`. There's a fairly big difference between the two. In particular, `multiprocessing` isn't constrained by the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) the way `threading` is.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I meant I tried multiprocess before threading.
Instead of t = threading.Thread(name="thread" + str(counter), target=example, args=(a,))
I tried multiprocessing in past:
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=example, args=(a,))  [I tried this instead of t in above script]
, my computer was slowed down if I give n more than 80 or so...

Answer (score 0):

You want to start a function in several threads at the same time. I never made it but an idea (not tested) would be 
- you start all 100 threads (and option you identify what is the usual time for starting all 100 threads 0.5s?)
- in your threads you make waiting for a signal: a "GO" anywhere or a time/date stored anywhere in a file which will be probably "time start of first thread + 0.5s". When the time is met in the thread, then you execute the function.
For the reason I dont know the inner life of threading, I cannot say to you if it will be for sure exactly the same time.